# How would I write a function to call another function Nth times in JavaScript without using a for or while loop?

Tags: javascript, function

I am new to coding and I have hit a snag that I can't seem to find an answer to... I am trying to write a function that will call another function nth number of times. I know when working with this data type that it is more difficult than with a number or string.

```
console.group("3 Times");
var hello = function(){
    console.log("Hello World!");
}
function call3Times(func) { 
    func(); 
    func(); 
    func(); 
}
function nthTimes(n, func){
    var hello = func;
    var nthHello = console.log(hello.repeat(n));
   return nthHello
}
call3Times(hello);
nthTimes(5, hello());
console.groupEnd();
```

so with this I keep getting that repeat can't be ran on an undefined variable. I know that in this case the function isn't referring to the variable but the function itself which it would view as a reference. So how would I work around that?

Comment: `nthTimes(5, hello());` doing this is actually executing the `hello` function and passing the value returned by the hello function to `nthTimes`. Instead, try this `nthTimes(5, hello);`  this way you are only passing a reference to the hello function which you can call later using `func()`

Answer (score 1):

First of all, welcome to the site and welcome to programming

You'll want to check out something called a [for loop](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp). They're utilities in programming that allow you to repeat a line or lines of code until a certain condition is met.

For example, in your scenario you could write

```
function nthTimes(n, func){
    for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      func();
    }
}
```

---

Also, it's worth noting that when you do the line `nthTimes(5, hello());`, by using `hello()` you are passing the result of the function `hello` instead of the reference to the function. It should be `nthTimes(5, hello);` instead.

Please feel free to ask if you'd like me to elaborate further

---

## Update

Here is a quick demonstration for you

```js
console.group("n Times");

var hello = function() {
  console.log("Hello World!");
}

function nthTimes(n, func) {
  for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    func();
  }
}

nthTimes(5, hello);
console.groupEnd();
```

---

## Update 2: Recursion

As per your comment below, this method takes out the need to use a loop utilizing the concept of [recursion](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/25545). See the below code snippet for an updated example

```js
function nthTimes(n, func){
    if (n < 1) return; // don't process if we don't have to
    
    func(); // call your function
    
    n = n - 1; // decrement the count
    
    nthTimes(n, func); // call this function again with new n
}

function hello() {
  console.log("Hi there");
}

nthTimes(5, hello);
```

The thing to note here is that your function calls itself. So if you call `nthTimes` with an n=2, the `func` function is called (in this example `hello()` is called), and you decrement n by one to account for the call. Then you call the `nthTimes` function *again*, but this time with n=1. Finally, once the function is called with n=0, the `return` call stops the function early before `func()` is called, and no further calculations are done. I've done the check for `n`'s value at the top of my function so that if a user were to input a number less than 1, the passed in function would not be called.

Comment: thanks for the warm welcome. Thanks for your input but the assignment i was working on said that i wasn't allowed to use a for or while loop unless specifically told too. which in this case i wasn't.

Comment: @Dayman3030 check out the update I've made to my question. And please feel free to ask any followup questions you may have

Answer (score 1):

As others pointed out:

- the `for` loop is the way to go. However, in comments you mention that no `for` loop should be used. In that case, you can use recursion.
- Functions don't have a `repeat` method.
- You called your `nthTimes` method with a wrong second argument: it should be `hello` (the function object), not the return value of one `hello()` execution: so without the parentheses:

  ```
  nthTimes(5, hello);
  ```

```js
function nthTimes(n, func) {
    if (n <= 0) return; // Don't call function (end recursion)
    func(); // call it once, ...
    nthTimes(n-1, func); // ...and n-1 times
};

var hello = function() {
    console.log("Hello World!");
}

nthTimes(5, hello);
```

### Alternative with `.repeat`

Since you used the `.repeat()` syntax, here is an alternative that makes that possible. A `repeatable` function defines the `repeat` method on a given function. In this alternative I have also added support for providing arguments, and using the `this` object:

```js
function repeatable(func) {
    // add a property to the function object; a new method for it:
    func.repeat = function (n, ...args) {
        if (n <= 0) return; // Don't call function (end recursion)
        func.call(this, ...args); // call it once, ...
        func.repeat(n-1, ...args); // ...and n-1 times
    };
    // The given function object is extended, but let's also return it 
    return func;
}

var hello = repeatable(function() {
    console.log("Hello World!");
});

hello.repeat(5);
```

Comment: I see what you are saying and that make complete sense but the assignment called for no for or while loop unless specifically asked to do so.

Comment: Oh, this was not mentioned in your question. Please update your question (click the edit link below it), and add this information and any other constraint.  I have updated my question, so it does not use a `for` loop.

Comment: Thanks and sorry for the confusion. I will edit the question now. thanks again

Answer (score 0):

I have a function that I keep re-writing called `times` (based on the old [PrototypeJS function Number#times](http://prototypejs.org/doc/latest/language/Number/prototype/times/)). It sounds like it'll do what you're after.

```
function toPosInt(number) {
    return Math.floor(Math.abs(number));
}

function times(number, handler, context) {

    let posInt = toPosInt(number) || 0;
    let i = 0;

    while (i < posInt) {

        handler.call(context, i);
        i += 1;

    }

    return posInt;

}
```

You'd then call it like any other function.

```
times(5, hello);
```

Answer (score 0):

There will be many approaches which successfully reproduce the effect you are looking to achieve.

The answer I have given below is:

- written in `ES2015+` syntax (the *"new"* versions of javascript); and
- uses a `callback` (which is a reference to a function passed as a parameter to another function (ie. the second function is able to access the first function)

```js
// A FUNCTION I WANT TO CALL BACK LATER

const logHelloWorld = () => {

  console.log('Hello World!');
}


// MY MAIN FUNCTION

const runFunctionRepeatedly = (callback, numberOfTimes) => {

  for (let i = 0; i < numberOfTimes; i++) {

    callback();    
  }
}


// CALLING MY MAIN FUNCTION

runFunctionRepeatedly(logHelloWorld, 3);
```

Answer (score 0):

According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat:

> The repeat() method constructs and returns a new string which contains the specified number of copies of the string on which it was called, concatenated together.

This means that it is used with `String` objects, and it will take one string and repeat it `n` times, storing the result as string.

Here is an example of using the .repeat() function:

```
var hello = "Hello World";

var repeated = hello.repeat(5);

console.log(repeated);
//expected output: > "Hello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello World"
```

Note that there is no spaces between each repeated `hello` - this is because there is no space at the end of `hello`, and it is repeated exactly.

For repeating a function multiple times, you could use a for loop:

```
function nthTimes(n, func) {
  for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    func(); 
  }
}

function hello() {
console.log("Hello World");
}

nthTimes(5, hello);
//expected output: > "Hello World" > "Hello World" > "Hello World" > "Hello World" > "Hello World"
```

Answer (score 0):

// @Dayman3030 is this what you're trying to achieve?

```
console.group("3 Times");

var hello = function(){
    return "Hello World! ";
}

function call3Times(n=3, func) { 
    for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      console.log(func());
 }
}

function nthTimes(n=3, func){
    var hello = func();
    var nthHello = hello.repeat(n);
    return console.log(nthHello);
}

call3Times(5, hello);
nthTimes(5, hello);
console.groupEnd();
```

Comment: I had a assignment for the class i am taking and that assignment is to return the call3times function nth times. The catch is that the instructions state to not use a for or while loop unless specifically told too. which in this case i wasn't.

Answer (score -1):

```
var hello = function(){
    console.log("Hello World!");
}
function nthTimes(n, func){
    for(let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
       func()
    }
}

nthTimes(5, hello);
```

**Explanation**

`nthTimes(5, hello());` doing this is actually executing the hello function and passing the value returned by the hello function to nthTimes. Instead, try this `nthTimes(5, hello);` this way you are only passing a reference to the hello function which you can call later using `func()`

Comment: Please consider testing your code before submitting it as an answer, especially if you're not going to provide any context! :)

Comment: As @TylerRoper said, you should include some explanation of your code, not just the code itself. Additionally, because you used `nthTimes(5, hello());` you will pass the result of the `hello` function instead of the reference to the function.

Comment: @TylerRoper i provided the explanation as comment above, forgot to pass here. And I missed that last part, you could have edited that.

Comment: @MickelsonMichael I did as a comment on the question, just forgot to add it here. And about the error, yeah I forgot to remove that while copying it from the question sorry about that edited it.

Comment: @Dimensionless Editing someone else's code without their explicit permission is almost never a good idea, regardless of what you're changing. If you edit your answer to include your comment above, I'll remove my downvote.